# Android getDeclaredFields value

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uns estudos de android, não manjo muito do assunto pois estou começando agora, gostaria de criar um simples mvc de CRUD, onde quero chamar `model.save()`;

Então criei a seguinte estrutura:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
Produto produto1 = new Produto(this);
produto1.setId(1);
produto1.setNome("CELULAR");
produto1.setPreco(5.5);
produto1.Save();
```

**Produto.java**

```java
@DatabaseTable (tableName = "produtos") 
public class Produto extends BaseModel{

     @DatabaseField(columnName="id",    columnType="INTEGER", primaryKey=true)
     private int id;

     @DatabaseField(columnName="nome", columnType="VARCHAR")
     private String nome;

     @DatabaseField(columnName="preco", columnType="DOUBLE", columnSize="10,9")
     private Double preco;

     @DatabaseField(columnName="endereco", columnType="TEXT", columnSize="50", canBeNull=true, defaultValue="NULL", unique=true)
     private Double endereco;

     public int getId() {return id;}
     public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
     public String getNome() {return nome;}
     public void setNome(String nome) {this.nome = nome;}
     public Double getPreco() {return preco;}
     public void setPreco(Double preco) {this.preco = preco;}

     public Produto(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }  
}
```

**DatabaseTable.java**

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) //can use in method only.
public @interface DatabaseTable {
    String tableName();  
}
```

**DatabaseField.java**

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD) //can use in method only.
public @interface DatabaseField {
     String columnName() default "";  
     String columnType(); 
     String defaultValue() default "";
     String columnSize() default "";
     boolean canBeNull() default true; 
     boolean unique() default false; 
     boolean primaryKey() default false; 
     boolean autoIncrement() default false; 
}
```

**BaseModel.java**

```java
public class BaseModel extends DBFactory<BaseModel> {
 public BaseModel(Context context) {
      super(context);
 }
}
```

**DBFactory.java**

```java
public class DBFactory<T> extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "VendasDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION  = 1;
    private final Context myContext;
    private static DBFactory mInstance = null;
    private static SQLiteDatabase myWritableDb;

    private Class t;
    public void set(Class t) { this.t = t; }
    public Class get() { return t; }

    public DBFactory(Context pContext){         
        super(pContext, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = pContext;
        this.set((Class) this.getClass());    
        Log.v("CreateTableOnModel",CreateTableOnModel());
    }

    public String Save()
    {
        Log.v("DBFactory", "SAVE()");
        Class clazz = get();

        DatabaseTable annot = (DatabaseTable) clazz.getAnnotation(DatabaseTable.class);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if(!annot.tableName().equals(""))
        {
            Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            Field idField = null;

            try {
               idField = clazz.getDeclaredField("id");      
               idField.setAccessible(true);
               Object b = idField.get(get().newInstance());
               Log.v("idField:", b.toString());
            } catch (Exception nsfe) {
               System.out.println(nsfe.toString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Erro:

```java
03-31 16:26:23.780: I/System.out(32048): java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class br.com.rlsystem.vendas.model.Produto; no empty constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque você está tentando criar uma instância sem passar argumentos no construtor de uma classe (`Produto`) que possui parâmetros:

```java
public Produto(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

Há duas saídas para resolver o problema:

1. Remova o construtor com argumentos e defina a dependência em um *setter*.
2. Recupere [uma referência para o construtor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) e utilize o [`newInstance` do Construtor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) passando os argumentos necessários.

---

***Atualização***

O método `get()` da classe `Field` precisa da instância de um objeto para recuperar o valor do atributo.

**O problema nesse caso é que você está criando um outro objeto vazio.**

Como `Produto` estende `DBFactory` indiretamente, o que você precisa é fazer referência ao próprio objeto, no caso:

```
Object b = idField.get(this);
```

Comment: Então eu não sei se estou fazendo corretamente para resgatar os valores que são setados na mainActivity, pois dei uma pesquisada e vi o método ".get()", só que ele espera um object, como estou tentando acessar a classe "Produto" tentei passando "newInstance()", como eu faria para passar o argumento para esse "newInstance()"? pois tentei:

Object b = idField.get(get().newInstance(this.myContext));
mas ele já nem deixa eu compilar, me da um erro:

The method newInstance() in the type Class is not applicable for the arguments (Context)

Comment: @Caião Faça conforme o item 2 descrito acima. Clique nos links para ver mais detalhes. Vai ficar algo como: `get().getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(context)`.

Comment: Funcionou, só tenho um problema, estou perdendo a referencia da model de produto, o valor está vindo vazio, creio eu que deveria passar a referencia dela passando no super, algo como public Produto(Context context) {super(context,this);}

Mas ele não me deixa fazer isso.

Comment: @Caião Eu respondi essa questão. Não é esse o problema. Acho que agora entendi o que você está tentando fazer. Vou editar a questão para refletir isso. Atualize esta página em 5 minutos.

Comment: Obrigado, isso resolveu meu problema!