# Erro com super(this) ao invocar um constructor em Java

Tags: java, android

Isso é permitido?

```
public Produto(Context context) {
    super(context, this);   
}
```

Está me dando erro :

> Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor

Estou tentando fazer um simples MVC para quando eu digitar `produto.Save()` eu consiga resgatar os valores que foram setados abaixo:

```
Produto produto1 = new Produto(this);
    produto1.setId(1);
    produto1.setNome("CELULAR");
    produto1.setPreco(5.5);
    produto1.Save();
```

O fonte do mesmo encontra-se nessa outra dúvida: [Android getDeclaredFields value](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11168/android-getdeclaredfields-value)

Comment: Você está tentando passar `this` num momento em que o objeto ainda está sendo construído e portanto não está pronto para ser referenciado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é necessário (e nem permitido) passar uma referência para o próprio objeto em seu construtor.

Para fazer referência ao si mesmo na superclasse, basta usar `this`, da mesma forma que na subclasse.

Não importa em qual nível da hierarquia de classes você esteja codificando, `this` sempre fará referência à instância que foi criada.

Comment: Então mas eu estou perdendo a referencia no código quando tento acessar:

 Object b = idField.get(get().getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this.myContext));

ele me retorna 0 ao invez do valor que setei na activityMain